# Can I compute the cube list in a neat way?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Can the following function be simplified with higher order functions, Monads or what have you?

```
cube list = [(x, y, z) | x <- list, y <- list, z <- list]
```

The function simply creates a list of all triple-permutations of the elements of the list. For example:

```
> cube [1..2]
[(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(2,2,1),(2,2,2)]
```

Comment: It's one perfectly simple line that fits into 80 columns. What more do you want? Higher order functions, monads, arrows and godknows what bling is often useful and justified, but here they add little, if anything. (Adjust buzzwords and it's appyable to toher languages as well!) Not to say it can't be simplified (it can, see the `zip` answer), but the attitude of "there must be a fancier way to write this more complexly"-esque questions annoys me.

Comment: @elnan: Good advice, but my code just screams "low level" and "code repetition" at me, and it makes me feel uncomfortable ;-)

Comment: Your code is the cleanest way I can think of to do this - don't worry too much about it.

Comment: if it makes you feel any better, list comprehensions are basically monads in disguise

Comment: List comprehensions are already quite succinct, beautiful and understandable. They read just like mathematical set comprehensions, where `<-` stands for ∈ (it even kind of looks like it if you squint). The only improvement I could imagine for the syntax is if you could do away with the repetitions of `list`, e.g. `[(x, y, z) | x, y, z <- list]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it gives you lists instead of tuples, you can use the `sequence` function in [Control.Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.1.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3Asequence):

```
> let list = [1..2]
> sequence [list, list, list]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
```

The `sequence` function is neat because, although its "intended" purpose is to take a list of actions, do them in order, and return their results in a list, using it on the list monad gives you combinations for free.

```
> sequence $ replicate 3 "01"
["000","001","010","011","100","101","110","111"]
```

Answer (score 10):

Going from Bill's answer, because this is code uses the list monad, we can use "applicative" style to do "with higher-order functions". Whether or not this is a good idea is left as an exercise for the engineer.

```
import Control.Applicative

cube :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a,b,c)]
cube x y z = (,,) <$> x <*> y <*> z
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind explaining it in a little more detail? That would be great! I have absolutely no idea what `(,,) <$> x <*> y <*> z` could possibly mean... (Also, `cube` should only take one argument (the list), not three.)

Comment: To answer the question, this should be `cube list = (,,) <$> list <*> list <*> list` .

Comment: @FredOverflow: Try `(,,) <$> getLine <*> getLine <*> getLine` in GHCi.  What `<*>` does is it takes two [motes](http://blog.plover.com/prog/haskell/monad-terminology.html) and applies the result of the first to the second.  `<$>` is similar, except it takes a pure function on the left side rather than a mote.  When applied to lists instead of IO actions, `(\x y z -> (x,y,z)) <$> list1 <*> list2 <*> list3` is exactly the same as `[(x,y,z) | x <- list1, y <- list2, z <- list3]`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: It uses the function (,,), which is of type "a -> b -> c -> (a, b, c)" and lifts it into the List monad.  It is equivalent to the monadic code in my answer, but is written in a different style.

Comment: @John: However, this should take one argument. :-]

Answer (score 7):

In fact, your list comprehension is a usage of the List monad.

Another way to write this is:

```
cube :: [a] -> [(a,a,a)]
cube list = do
  x <- list
  y <- list
  z <- list
  return (x, y, z)
```

Comment: I think it's worth emphasizing that this answer, the original list comprehension, and Edward Z. Yang's `Applicative` version are not merely accomplishing the *same task*, but are in fact different ways to express the *exact same idea*.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't really a serious answer, but I have to suggest it anyway.  Mostly for the sake of craziness.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Instances

cube :: [a] -> [(a, a, a)]
cube = join . join $ liftM3 (,,)
```

Have fun with that one. :)

Comment: Oh, good point.  I guess I'll add a type signature to defeat it.

Comment: That is quite the lovely example of the pointless obfuscation monad in action!

Comment: should be noted that `cube a = liftM3 (,,) a a a` also does the trick. Although I do like your point free answer a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

To model after what Joey Adams did:

```
g>replicateM 3 [1..2]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
```

For the full solution(pass it a list and get 3-tuples), something like this can be done:

```
g>let cube = map (\(a:b:c:_) -> (a, b, c)) . replicateM 3
cube :: [t] -> [(t, t, t)]
(0.00 secs, 526724 bytes)
g>cube [1..2]
[(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(2,2,1),(2,2,2)]
it :: [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]
```

But IMHO, Edward Z. Yang's solution reigns supreme.

Answer (score 2):

Who needs monads if you can have bits?

```
import Data.Bits

cube :: [(Int,Int,Int)]
cube = map tuple [0..7] where
   tuple x = (1 + div (x .&. 4)  4, 1 + div (x .&. 2)  2, 1 + x .&. 1)
```

Comment: Oh, a downvoter without any sense of humour. Do I **really** have to stress that I don't mean this serious?